# I can't make word files using my powershell script via PHP

Tags: php, shell, powershell

So to summarize the problem, I have a powershell script that executes word and produces a word file (alongside a pdf version of it but it doesn't really change anything).

if I launch it with my PC's shell, it works fine and creates everything. but if I launch it from my php page via shell_exec, everything is done except the creation of the word files.

```php
var_dump(shell_exec('powershell -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -File C:\wamp64\www\test\a\Add-ADUserENSG1.ps1 -Prenom "'.$prenom.'" -NomFamille "'.$nom.'" -Description "'.$desc.'" -Type "'.$type));
```

as expected, the script is executed producing a new user and a password but doesn't produce the word files.
I really don't know why.
thank you for helping!

Comment: What user account is the web server/php running under? Might be that that account has never launched Word and get's stuck on first startup

Comment: Maybe PHP cannot launch Powershell due to environment configuration?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I use wamp on my admin account so I don't think its a problem

Comment: @CyprienAubry Actually, the powershell is executed (creation of an account and its password) but the creation of a file isn't executed :/

Comment: Change the script so that it will just create a file in, say, c:\temp. Does that work? If it does, add logging statements to your script to see which part is executed.

Comment: @vonPryz Like I said I tried many locations but only the account creating was executed

Comment: Any logs?  Write permissions on destination folder?

Comment: @Nic3500 I made a var dump to see what happens does that interests you?

Comment: @Nic3500 and I tried to add a simple text file and it worked

Answer (score 0):

So I tried many things and it didn't solve the problem. 
So I tried to change my local server from WAMP to XAMPP and... it worked!
Now everything is executed as it should be.
Don't ask me why I don't know.
Anyway, thank you for your help folks!